# Could not install 'xlwings' in my Ubuntu machine

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to install `xlwings` module in my Ubuntu machine but failed as below

```
pip3 install xlwings
Collecting xlwings
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/c9/6bb1849dbee6e8a40beb9a0d21df9787bee45cda1d0bb575a0cd388dd260/xlwings-0.15.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-u90aes_a/xlwings/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
        raise OSError("currently only Windows and OSX are supported.")
    OSError: currently only Windows and OSX are supported.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-u90aes_a/xlwings/
```

What is the resolution of this error? Is xlwings not supported in Ubuntu? I also tried to install the same manually as below but failed too.

```
cd xlwings
python setup.py install
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**Update on 10th July 2019**

I ran code `export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1` and then installed `xlwings`. Installation was fine.
However when I tried to import `xlwings` in Python, that failed with below error:

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xlwings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlwings/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import _xlmac as xlplatform
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 10, in <module>
    import aem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aem'
```

I could not install package `aem` with below error:

```
pip3 install aem
Collecting aem
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/aem/
```

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Per the docs and [this](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/746) issue, xlwings is not supported on linux

Comment: As the error message very clearly says: *OSError: currently only Windows and OSX are supported.* That is because `xlwings` doesn't read Excel files itself. Instead it starts up Excel and gets it to do the heavy lifting. That in turn means you have to have Excel installed. You could try using `openpyxl` instead. It reads and writes Excel files natively and doesn't need a copy of Excel.

Comment: Thanks  BoarGules. But problem with openpyxl is if the Excel file has graph, charts etc. then they are discarded. Any solution to this?

Comment: That aem module is macOS only. xlwings has gone "it not windows, I don't support Linux, so it must be a Mac machine" and then run off and tried to find aem. Linux is not supported for xlwings. If you must have xlwings on Linux for usage then you will need an installed Excel. You will need to take the wine route.

Answer (score 5):

please run this command before ruining pip install xlwings (for linux users)

export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1

nice coding

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I now could install xlwings, but could not import it. Updated my post with a detailed error log. Any workaround?

Comment: This flag was specifically designed to be an option that has the user declare "I understand this won't work, but I want to install it anyway".

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially install [Anaconda for Windows](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe) within [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) and then also install [Excel within Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11) and then maybe, maybe (no promises), you might find that `xlwings`... just... might... work... ... but there will likely be many speed bumps along the way...

Comment: What kind of serious solution is this?

Comment: The only solution that actually has a chance of working with xlwings in Linux. You already need Excel on Linux to be able to use xlwings, so you already need wine. I have quite a bit of success with winpy inside wine on Linux before -- http://winpython.sourceforge.net/. For some reason I found Python 3.5 was easiest to get running within wine.